# Why is Recycler view data on the row is gone when i click on the same row's child view?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I have created a recycler view view which will have cardView rows,in the card view i have put a layout,on click of it a childview will open, when i click on the layout, child view is coming but the data which is already populated on the card is dissappearing.And when I scroll down the child view itself disappears and the data on the card is populated again.I am not able to find a solution for this from a long time, please help me with this.This is how I am adding the child view in the adapter

```
    @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            mAdapter = new ViewOrderAdapter(orderList);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cancelledcardview, null);
            final RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.cancelledcardview, null);

            Log.i("TAG", "onclickmethod" + parent);
            final View child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vieworder_layout, null);
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView)child. findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            Log.i("TAG", "onclickmethod" + recyclerView);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            parent.addView(child);
            ImageView cancelButton= (ImageView)child.findViewById(R.id.cancelbutton);
            cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.i("TAG", "onclickmethodcancel button" );
                    parent.removeView(child);

                }
            });
            prepareMovieData();
            cv.addView(parent);
        }
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain the click state. when you scroll the list the onBind method is called again and it populates the old card again.
I Suggest 
-create 1 more variable(isClicked) in your model and set it true when you click it. 
-In your onBind method of adapter you have to again write the code for creating this child view.

Or you can use ExpandableListView this will handle the state more gracefully.

Comment: I am not able to add child view in onBind method as i need to pass context and get reference of recycler view and adapter,How to do that?@peeyush pathak

Comment: You will have the context in adapter because you are using it in onCreateViewHolder because you have to inflate the a new view.